# MySQL 'UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY' without a unique column?

Tags: mysql

What are peoples' thoughts on the most performance efficient way to do the following query:

- 3 column table
- if the combination of `col_1` and `col_2` values already exist  `UPDATE col_3`
- else `INSERT` new row

I assume i need some kind if UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY (which i've never used before), however I do not have a 'KEY' but instead a pair of two values (columns)  to make a key...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` key out of multiple columns (called a composite key) in MySQL, which'll allow `ON DUPLICATE KEY` to work just fine.

```
// create a composite index
CREATE INDEX my_composite_index ON my_table (column1, column2);

// insert or update
INSERT INTO my_table (column1, column2) VALUES ('value1', 'value2') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column3=column3+1;
```

Comment: thanks ceejayoz, are you able to give me some sample code for ON DUPLICATE KEY please?

Comment: awesome, really kind of you - thanks so much! I should quickly check - i only need to create the index once right?

Comment: Yeah. Indexes can be very helpful for performance - I advise reading the MySQL docs on them.

Answer (score 1):

Most efficient way is to create UNIQUE KEY and use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

Slower way is to:
LOCK TABLE
SELECT TABLE (you need an index anyway for the best performance)
if exists, UPDATE
else INSERT
UNLOCK TABLES

Answer (score -1):

**Edit: Ignore my suggestions**

You can use a composite key as ceejayoz said, however I think you need REPLACE INTO instead of UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY because REPLACE also inserts if no duplicate is found.

Note: I don't know the workings of UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY but it sounds like it doesn't perform inserts.

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is for `INSERT` queries only, actually. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html `REPLACE INTO` is a bad choice because it doesn't allow you to update just a field or two - you have to specify values for the entire row.