# Composite Unique Index On Duplicate Update

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, duplicates

I want to use INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in mysql and i have a composite unique index.

product_id and language_id is composite index. And unique.

This is product_language table.

> product_id  = 1 
>   language_id = 1 
>   title       = 'Product Name in Any
>   Language'

And other fields...

Here is my code. I want to change product names in any language. If i want to change french language_id is 2 if german 3 etc.

Every language translations must be unique for that reason i created composite index.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".PREFIX."product_language(product_id, language_id, title) "
          . "VALUES (:id, 1, :data) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE title = :data";
```

in [mysql manuel](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) there is a note : "avoid to use composite index"

How can i do this ? It is not working

Comment: Can you include a link to the reference in the manual.

Comment: What is `PREFIX`.  You say you have a `product_language` table, but you are actually updating `<PREFIX>product_language`.  That may be your problem.

Comment: i include the link and the sentence is "In general, you should try to avoid using an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause on tables with multiple unique indexes."

Comment: PREFIX is not related with this topic. It is a contant of my database prefix.

Comment: You may want to see the answer by ceejayoz here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180913/mysql-update-on-duplicate-key-without-a-unique-column