# SQL - UPDATE or INSERT by checking two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm somewhat new to SQL so I hope this doesn't come off as a dumb question. I am trying to create a scheduling program where the table is as such:

```
event_id    worker_id    date            shift_type
1           1            2014-01-01      Labour Day Shift
2           1            2014-01-02      Labour Night Shift
3           2            2014-01-01      Engineer Day Shift
4           2            2014-01-02      Engineer Night Shift
5           3            2014-01-01      Electrician Day Shift
6           3            2014-01-02      Electrician Day Shift
```

As you can see, I treat each "shift" as an event. When I insert into the database, I would like a way to check if 'worker_id' and 'date' already exist in the table under the same row and if so use UPDATE rather then INSERT. Please note, that neither 'worker_id' or 'date' is unique, however the combination of the two in a single row would be unique.

Comment: See `REPLACE` syntax.

Comment: Just to add more details to i486 comment, make an unique index of the worker_id and date fields to enforce the uniqueness, and then you can use "replace" instead of insert/update leaving all the checking to the DB.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL 'UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY' without a unique column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180913/mysql-update-on-duplicate-key-without-a-unique-column)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `on duplicate key` update.  But first, you need a unique index on `worker_id` and `date`:

```
create unique index idx_table_worker_date on table(worker_id, date);

insert into table(worker_id, date, shift_type)
    values (@worker_id, @date, @shift_type)
    on duplicate key update shift_type = values(shift_type);
```

The `table` is a placeholder for your table name.  The variables starting with `@` are placeholders for the values you want to insert.

Answer (score 1):

Since the worker_id and date in combination are unique, you can rely on the INSERT to throw a duplicate error:

```
INSERT INTO table (event_id, worker_id, date, shift_type) 
    VALUES (1, 1, @date, @shift) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE event_id=1, shift_type=values(shift_type);
```

See [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) documentation.

To clarify, you can declare multiple columns to be unique in combination:

```
UNIQUE KEY 'key_name' (column_one, column_two, ... etc.)
```

See [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) and [CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) for further clarification.

Comment: From my understanding, in order to use this 'worker_id' and 'date' have to be either: UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY in which they are not since they are only unique as a combination of being together, not re-inforced by mysql. Am I not understanding something? Sorry if I am the issue right now...

Comment: When inserting into a table with a unique key (which can be a combination of several columns), the INSERT statement will enforce that constraint.

Answer (score 0):

```
// create a composite index
CREATE INDEX my_composite_index ON my_table (worker_id, date);

// insert or update
INSERT INTO my_table (worker_id, date, shift_type) VALUES ('value1', 'value2', 'value3') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE shift_type=shift_type+1;
```