# MySQL: INSERT or UPDATE if already exists

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table setup (much like the WordPress `usermeta` table) which allows keys and values to be stored for a given user.

`ID    UserID    MetaKey    MetaValue`

`ID` is the primary, auto increment column, `UserID` is an `INT` value of the user's ID.

My current insert statement looks like:

```
INSERT INTO user_meta (`UserID`, `MetaKey`, `MetaValue`) VALUES
    (5, firstkey, firstvalue),
    (5, secondkey, secondvalue)
```

This works when inserting new values, but how would I update the query so that if a row exists in which the `UserID` and `MetaKey` values match the one being inserted, update the existing `MetaValue` instead of inserting a new row?

Comment: Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [SQL - UPDATE or INSERT by checking two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27808276/sql-update-or-insert-by-checking-two-columns).

Comment: @BillKarwin I read those examples and they seem to all allude to on duplicate of the primary key, and that's not what I'm doing.

Comment: @JROB create a unique index based on (UserId, MetaKey) and then follow Bill Karwin's advice. It will work just as well for unique index as it will for primary keys, as the article clearly states in it's very first paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'd need to define a unique constraint for the UserID and MetaKey combination:

```
 ALTER TABLE usermeta ADD CONSTRAINT UserID_MetaKey_combination UNIQUE (UserID, MetaKey);
```

Note: you won't be able to add the constraint if you already have non-unique combinations of UserID and MetaKey values in the table.

After the table has the constraint, the following query will insert if the UserID and MetaKey is unique, otherwise will update the MetaValue for the found combination:

```
   INSERT INTO usermeta (`UserID`, `MetaKey`, `MetaValue`) VALUES
       (5, "firstkey", "firstvalue"),
       (5, "secondkey", "secondvalue")
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE MetaValue=values(MetaValue)
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed to know. I know the pieces were in the documentation, but I wasn't able to figure it out. Thank you.